# Как эффективно перебрать процентные распределения?

Tags: python, алгоритм

Необходимо с помощью Python решить задачу:
Есть набор финансовых инструментов (пусть 10 штук). Есть сумма инвестиционного портфеля.

Необходимо найти ВСЕ возможные варианты распределения долей от общей суммы инвестиционного портфеля, приходящихся на каждый инструмент(включая 0%).
Общая сумма должна быть = 100%. Шаг задан (пусть 2%). Т.е. значения процентов 0,2,4,6..100%.
Пример: 
    [14, 6, 10, 6, 10, 0, 16, 24, 2, 12].

Вариант влоб:

```
step = 2.0
num_of_tickers = 10
steps = math.floor(100.0 / step) + 1
share_lst = [idx * step for idx in range(0, steps)]
comb_all = itertools.product(share_lst, repeat=num_of_tickers)
comb_res = list(filter(lambda x: sum(x) == 100.0, comb_all))
```

Считает ОЧЕНЬ долго.

Пробовал ухищрения, сокращающие набор по условию <=100%:

```
comb_all = itertools.product(share_lst, repeat=5)
comb_all_lst = list(filter(lambda x: sum(x) <= 100.0, comb_all))
for lst in comb_all_lst:
    for lst_1 in comb_all_lst:
        if (sum(lst) + sum(lst_1)) == 100.0:
            comb_res.append(lst + lst_1)
```

Уже реальнее, но все равно долго.

Как добиться более быстрой скорости работы?

Пример для step = 25.0 и числа инструментов num_of_tickers = 4:

Возможные значения процентной доли:

```
[0.0, 25.0, 50.0, 75.0, 100.0]
```

На выходе должна быть таблица распределений вида:

```
0,   0,   0,   100
0,   0,   25,  75
0,   25,  0,   75
25,  0,   0,   75
25,  0,   25,  50
...
100, 0,   0,   0
```

Comment: в вашем вопросе не определены: `num_of_tickers`, `MAX_SHARE_SUM`

Comment: Да, прошу прощения, поправил. num_of_tickers-число инструментов. MAX_SHARE_SUM = 100%

Comment: Входной таблицы в принципе нет. Из входных данных - число инструментов и шаг процентной доли. В вопрос добавил пример для step = 25.0

Comment: мда, задачка нетривиальная - с наскока не решить... Надо подумать...

Comment: @jfs, Насколько я понял вики, да композиция числа 100 длиной = числу инструментов. Части композиции берутся с учетом шага(step), нулевые части композиции допустимы.

Comment: Длина 10. Сумма 100%

Comment: "Считает ОЧЕНЬ долго..." - это сколько?

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/88241)

Comment: на мой взгляд у jfs получилось такое огромное количество распределений: 12565671261 в результате увеличения количества финансовых инструментов,  в строке 72 2 0 4 16 0 2 0 2 2 есть 4 финансовых инструмента "2", а на самом деле он один "Пример: [14, 6, 10, 6, 10, 0, 16, 24, 2, 12]", но может быть применен многократно

Comment: а зря удалили мой вопрос, хочется помочь человеку...

Comment: @craneua Вы, видимо, не совсем верно поняли вопрос. Число финансовых  инструментов фиксировано в исходных условиях. А 2 в вашем примере - это процентного доля исходного капитала, приходящегося на данный инструмент

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Задача сводится к перебору [композиций/разложений натурального числа (weak сompositions)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0) для `100 / step` целого числа:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import math

step = 2
n = 100 // step
k = 10 # количество инструментов

def binom(n, k):
    f = math.factorial
    return f(n) // (f(k) * f(n - k))

print("Количество распределений:", binom(n+k-1, n))
for comp in weak_compositions(k, n):
    assert len(comp) == k and sum(n*step for n in comp) == 100
    print(*[n*step for n in comp])
```

где `weak_composition(k, n)` это читаемая реализация из [ответа @user3736966 на схожий вопрос на Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36748940/4279):

```
def weak_compositions(boxes, balls, parent=tuple()):
    if boxes > 1:
        for i in range(balls + 1):
            yield from weak_compositions(boxes - 1, i, parent + (balls - i,))
    else:
        yield parent + (balls,)
```

Пример:

```
>>> print(*[' + '.join(map(str, c)) for c in weak_compositions(3, 5)], sep='\n')
5 + 0 + 0
4 + 1 + 0
4 + 0 + 1
3 + 2 + 0
3 + 1 + 1
3 + 0 + 2
2 + 3 + 0
2 + 2 + 1
2 + 1 + 2
2 + 0 + 3
1 + 4 + 0
1 + 3 + 1
1 + 2 + 2
1 + 1 + 3
1 + 0 + 4
0 + 5 + 0
0 + 4 + 1
0 + 3 + 2
0 + 2 + 3
0 + 1 + 4
0 + 0 + 5
```

#### Результат для `step == 25`, `number_of_tickets == 4`

```
Количество распределений: 35
100 0 0 0
75 25 0 0
75 0 25 0
75 0 0 25
50 50 0 0
50 25 25 0
50 25 0 25
50 0 50 0
50 0 25 25
50 0 0 50
25 75 0 0
25 50 25 0
25 50 0 25
25 25 50 0
25 25 25 25
25 25 0 50
25 0 75 0
25 0 50 25
25 0 25 50
25 0 0 75
0 100 0 0
0 75 25 0
0 75 0 25
0 50 50 0
0 50 25 25
0 50 0 50
0 25 75 0
0 25 50 25
0 25 25 50
0 25 0 75
0 0 100 0
0 0 75 25
0 0 50 50
0 0 25 75
0 0 0 100
```

#### Результат для `step == 2`, `number_of_tickets == 10`

```
Количество распределений: 12565671261
100 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
98 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
98 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
...
72 2 0 4 16 0 2 0 2 2
72 2 0 4 16 0 2 0 0 4
72 2 0 4 16 0 0 6 0 0
...
```

Связанные вопросы:

- [Next Composition of n into k parts - does anyone have a working algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4647120/4279)
- [Efficient lazy weak compositions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/92647/34983)

Comment: Благодарю, в деталях еще буду разбираться. На 6 инструментах скорость расчета быстрее на порядок, чем в моем варианте.

Answer (score 0):

to Rapohin Dmitriy
Я и взял ваш пример: [14, 6, 10, 6, 10, 0, 16, 24, 2, 12], только для ускорения отсортировал его по убыванию.

```
import sys
import datetime

def variant(i0, i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8, i9):
    ls = [i0, i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8, i9]
    k0 = sorted(ls, reverse=True)[0]
    k1 = sorted(ls, reverse=True)[1]
    k2 = sorted(ls, reverse=True)[2]
    k3 = sorted(ls, reverse=True)[3]
    k4 = sorted(ls, reverse=True)[4]
    k5 = sorted(ls, reverse=True)[5]
    k6 = sorted(ls, reverse=True)[6]
    k7 = sorted(ls, reverse=True)[7]
    k8 = sorted(ls, reverse=True)[8]
    k9 = sorted(ls, reverse=True)[9]
    pa = 100
    if k0 == 0: r0 = 1
    else: r0 = int(pa / k0) + 1
    if k1 == 0: r1 = 1
    else: r1 = int(pa / k1) + 1
    if k2 == 0: r2 = 1
    else: r2 = int(pa / k2) + 1
    if k3 == 0: r3 = 1
    else: r3 = int(pa / k3) + 1
    if k4 == 0: r4 = 1
    else: r4 = int(pa / k4) + 1
    if k5 == 0: r5 = 1
    else: r5 = int(pa / k5) + 1
    if k6 == 0: r6 = 1
    else: r6 = int(pa / k6) + 1
    if k7 == 0: r7 = 1
    else: r7 = int(pa / k7) + 1
    if k8 == 0: r8 = 1
    else: r8 = int(pa / k8) + 1
    if k9 == 0: r9 = 1
    else: r9 = int(pa / k9) + 1
    c = 0
    s = 0
    print(k0,' ',k1,' ',k2,' ',k3,' ',k4,' ',k5,' ',k6,' ',k7,' ',k8,' ',k9)
    for c0 in range(r0):
        s0 = c0 * k0
        for c1 in range(r1):
            s1 = c1 * k1
            if s1 + s0 > pa: break
            for c2 in range(r2):
                s2 = c2 * k2
                if s2 + s1 + s0 > pa: break
                for c3 in range(r3):
                    s3 = c3 * k3
                    if s3 + s2 + s1 + s0 > pa: break
                    for c4 in range(r4):
                        s4 = c4 * k4
                        if s4 + s3 + s2 + s1 + s0 > pa: break
                        for c5 in range(r5):
                            s5 = c5 * k5
                            if s5 + s4 + s3 + s2 + s1 + s0 > pa: break
                            for c6 in range(r6):
                                s6 = c6 * k6
                                if s6 + s5 + s4 + s3 + s2 + s1 + \
                                    s0 > pa: break
                                for c7 in range(r7):
                                    s7 = c7 * k7
                                    if s7 + s6 + s5 + s4 + s3 + s2 + \
                                        s1 + s0 > pa: break
                                    for c8 in range(r8):
                                        s8 = c8 * k8
                                        if s8 + s7 + s6 + s5 + s4 + \
                                            s3 + s2 + s1 + s0 > pa: break
                                        for c9 in range(r9):
                                            s9 = c9 * k9
                                            s = s9 + s8 + s7 + s6 + s5 + \
                                                s4 + s3 + s2 + s1 + s0
                                            if s < pa:
                                                pass
                                            elif s == pa:
                                                print(c0*k0, c1*k1, c2*k2,
                                                    c3*k3, c4*k4, c5*k5, c6*k6,
                                                    c7*k7, c8*k8, c9*k9)
                                                c += 1
                                            else: break
    print('Всего вариантов: ', c)
    return

print(datetime.datetime.now())
variant(14, 6, 10, 6, 10, 0, 16, 24, 2, 12)
print(datetime.datetime.now())
```

А если выводить результаты в файл и учесть все замечания критиканов, а не помощников в решении вопроса, то модифицировав код написанный за 5 минут получим результат за 1 секунду:

2016-07-04 11:27:36.710029
24   16   14   12   10   10   6   6   2   0
Всего вариантов:  23436
2016-07-04 11:27:37.442615

Comment: Это жесть какая-то. Зачем для каждого k0 - k9 заново сортируете ls? Это точно не оптимизация, это антиоптимизация. Можно было просто сделать `k = sorted(ls, reverse=True)`, потом циклом инициализировать список `r` (а не 10 отдельных переменных).

Comment: @craneua, не могли бы вы привести результат работы вашего варианта для условий step == 25%, число инструментов == 4? Тогда мы сможем сравнить его с тем, что есть в ответе у jfs.

Comment: дайте, пожалуйста процентные значения этих 4 инструментов

Comment: также 35 вариантов

Comment: @craneua, для решения задачи никаких более входных данных кроме шага и количества инструментов не требуется. Результат работы должен быть как в ответе jfs под заголовком "Результат для step == 25, number_of_tickets == 4". Если Вам требуются какие-то еще входные данные, значит Вы, все-таки, неверно поняли задачу.

Comment: я уже понял, результат 35 вариантов