# Как заполнить массив всеми возможными комбинациями единиц и нулей?

Tags: php, массивы, алгоритм, комбинаторика

Здравствуйте! Второй день не могу найти решение такой, казалось бы, простой задачи. Имеется количество ячеек **f** и определенное количество монет **c**. В каждую ячейку можно положить только одну монету, задача состоит в том, что нужно вычислить количество возможных комбинаций (с этим я справился быстро, есть формулы для этого) и записать все возможные комбинации в текстовый файл. Чтобы было понятнее, вот как выглядит файл с комбинациями (случай с 5 ячейками и 2 монетами, первая строка - номера ячеек):

- 1 2 3 4 5
- 1 1 0 0 0
- 1 0 1 0 0
- 1 0 0 1 0
- 1 0 0 0 1
- 0 1 1 0 0
- 0 1 0 1 0
- 0 1 0 0 1
- 0 0 1 1 0
- 0 0 1 0 1
- 0 0 0 1 1

Чтобы записать все это дело в текстовый файл, надо построить какой-то массив, вот тут у меня возникают трудности. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить такую задачу? Склоняюсь больше всего к решению с рекурсией, но не могу понять, как это сделать.

Answer (score 1):

Можно взять `c` монет (обозначенных единичками) и добавить между ними (`c+1` промежуток, включая слева и справа на краю) `f - c` нулей, чтобы заполнить все `f` ячеек.

К примеру в случае с двумя монетами и пятью ячейками, можно добавить нули в три места (обозначенные звёздочкой `*`):

```
k m n
*1*1*
```

В каждое место можно добавить от  0 до `(f-c)` нулей:

```
<?php

$Z = 5 - 2; // (f - c) == number of Zeros
for ($k = 0; $k <= $Z; $k++) {
  for ($m = 0; $m <= ($Z-$k); $m++) {
    $n = $Z - $k - $m;
    echo str_repeat("0", $k);
    echo 1;
    echo str_repeat("0", $m);
    echo 1;
    echo str_repeat("0", $n);
    echo "\n";
  }
}

?>
```

Это печатает ровно `f!/(c! * (f-c)!)` строк (<sub>f</sub>C<sub>c</sub>), что может быть заметно лучше чем  фильтровать все возможные 2<sup>f</sup> битовые строки.

#### [Результат](http://ideone.com/H3sgtW)

```
11000
10100
10010
10001
01100
01010
01001
00110
00101
00011
```

В такой постановке задача сводится к [разбиению  `(f-c)` числа  на  `(c+1)` частей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/534149/23044):

```
11000 <=> 0 0 3
10100 <=> 0 1 2
10010 <=> 0 2 1
10001 <=> 0 3 0
01100 <=> 1 0 2
01010 <=> 1 1 1
01001 <=> 1 2 0
00110 <=> 2 0 1
00101 <=> 2 1 0
00011 <=> 3 0 0
```

#### [Пример](http://ideone.com/zcY2mS)

```
<?php

function weak_compositions($nboxes, $nballs, $parent="", $nested=0) {
  $one = $nested ? "1" : "";
  if ($nboxes > 1) {
    for ($i = 0; $i <= $nballs; $i++) {
  weak_compositions($nboxes - 1, $i, $parent . $one . str_repeat("0", $nballs - $i), 1);
    }
  } else {
    echo $parent . $one .  str_repeat("0", $nballs) . "\n";
  }
}

$f=5;
$c=2;
weak_compositions($c+1, $f-$c);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Опишу алгоритм, возможно, не идеальный, но рабочий.

1) Заводим цикл с счетчиком от 0 до с^f, в вашем случае от 0 до 32.

2) На каждой итерации преобразовываем счетчик в с-ричную систему, получая в вашем случае все числа от 00000 до 11111. Это будут все возможные варианты наличия монет в ячейках.

3) Т.к. в вашем случае монеты всего 2, то следует отбрасывать на каждой итерации "плохие" варианты, т.е. где сумма ячеек с монетами не равна 2. "Хорошие" варианты сохранять.